# Jmeter: Invalid token response is received even after parameterizing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am new to performance testing. I have a couple Thread groups, the first thread group is for logging into the application and performing search. The second thread group is to load a particular page which requires authentication.

Issues: In the first thread group I have used JSON extractor and extracted the authentication token. I am passing the same token to through HTTP Header Manager for other thread groups too. But i receive a response like  {"detail":"Invalid token."}

Is there a better way to do this? Is it possible to set Env for authentication token and use it across all thread groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads

So you cannot pass a JMeter Variable between Thread Groups, you need to convert it to a JMeter Property using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st Thread Group and access the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd Thread Group. See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more detailed information.

---

A more elegant solution would be using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin, this way you will ensure that threads which require token from the 2nd Thread Group won't start unless a valid token is available.